# Text label within dotted line around nodes

Tags: showlabels

[image: Text should be added where it is in the picture]

Hello, would like to add some text where it is put in the picture. Already tried a few things but did not get an easy solution. Could someone help me out please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc}

%%% styles for Figure: Main areas of leadership affected by Digital Transformation %%%
\tikzstyle{digital} = [rectangle, rounded corners, align=left, draw=black, fill=gray!20, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [thick,-,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.2cm]

%%% NODES %%%
\node (competitive)[digital] {Competitive Landscape};                           
\node (customer) [digital, left of=competitive, xshift=-2cm] {Customer relationship};           
\node (work) [digital, right of=competitive, xshift=2cm] {People/Work environment};

%%% LINES %%%
\draw [line] (competitive) -- (customer);
\draw [line] (competitive) -- (work);

%%% RECTANGLES %%%
\draw[thick,dotted]    ($(customer.north west)+(-0.25,0.25)$) rectangle ($(work.south east)+(0.25,-0.6)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Three pillars} \label{fig:leadership_digital}
\end{figure}   

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the fit-library to create a node surrounding your other boxes and then create another node at the south position with your text. This node can then have a white background if you like.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, fit}

%%% styles for Figure: Main areas of leadership affected by Digital Transformation %%%
\tikzstyle{digital} = [rectangle, rounded corners, align=left, draw=black, fill=gray!20, text width=3cm]
\tikzstyle{line} = [thick,-,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.2cm]

%%% NODES %%%
\node (competitive)[digital] {Competitive Landscape};                           
\node (customer) [digital, left of=competitive, xshift=-2cm] {Customer relationship};           
\node (work) [digital, right of=competitive, xshift=2cm] {People/Work environment};

%%% LINES %%%
\draw [line] (competitive) -- (customer);
\draw [line] (competitive) -- (work);

%%% RECTANGLES %%%
\node[draw, thick, dotted, rounded corners, inner xsep=1em, inner ysep=1em, fit=(work) (customer)] (box) {};
\node[fill=white] at (box.south) {Text Here};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Three pillars} \label{fig:leadership_digital}
\end{figure}   

\end{document}
```

If you need more whitespace before and/or afterwards, an easy (but probably not so nice) way is to just put a `\quad` before and after your text.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 2):

with `tikz` libraries `chains`, `fit` and `positioning` is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 node distance = 10mm and 5mm,
   start chain = going right,
digital/.style = {rounded corners, draw, fill=gray!20,
                  text width=3cm, align=flush center, %left,
                  on chain, join=by line},
   line/.style = {thick,-Stealth}
                    ]
%%% NODES %%%
\node (n1) [digital] {Customer relationship};
\node (n2) [digital] {Competitive Landscape};
\node (n3) [digital] {People/Work environment};
%%% dotted RECTANGLE %%%
\node[draw, thick, dotted, inner sep=3ex, yshift=-1ex,
      fit=(n1) (n3)] (box) {};
\node[fill=white, inner xsep=1ex] at (box.south) {Text Here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Three pillars}
\label{fig:leadership_digital}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

note: your code assume, that nodes "digital" are connected by arrows, but on images are simple lines. if you prefer to have only lines, than change `line` style to `line/.style = {thick,-}`